# How to automate export in Tilemill?

Tags: tilemill

I have installed Tilemill to export my map as mbtiles,and I used mbutil to export as PNG images & UTFGrid.So forth,I have a Tilemill project with MSS(Carto) files.Now the data source is going to change weekly and I wish to automate this action.

So does Tilemill support command-line scripting or something else to export my project with given properties ??

Current System :
Windows 7 x64

**EDIT in response to @Sunil:**

> TileMill doesn't have any features for automatically manipulating your Carto stylesheets, but you could use a bash script to manipulate the Carto files directly. TileMill also has an export command that can be called from bash.

On Mac OS X, you could run a command like this in the Terminal for more details about using the export command:

/Applications/TileMill.app/Contents/Resources/node /Applications/TileMill.app/Contents/Resources/index.js export --help

**The exact command depends on how you installed TileMill**

Unfortunately,same command for Mac OS X does not work on my current system.What does the last sentence mean,is there different installations of Tilemill ?

Comment: helpful for you http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/tilemill/428-automation-of-exports

Answer (score 12):

I found it at last.Tilemill commands should run via **node** that included in the same directory with index.js file.I was trying to run directly index.js as `index.js export ..` which is not working.

@Sunil's redirection to support page allowed me to install ubuntu and see code was working then i realized that it was all working with nodejs functionality.After opening Tilemill GUI,it also works in `http://localhost:20009/` as well.Then I got that commands should be working with node.

Therefore
we must type on Windows 7 (x64)

```
node index.js export (..options..)
```

on Ubuntu

```
./index.js export (..options..)
```

Also I found all available commands

> **Options:**
>   
> --**format=[format]**                 Export format (png|pdf|svg|mbtiles|upload|sync). (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**bbox=[xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]**      Comma separated coordinates of bounding box to export. (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**minzoom=[zoom]**                  MBTiles: minimum zoom level to export. (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**maxzoom=[zoom]**                  MBTiles: maximum zoom level to export. (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**width=[width]**                   Image: image width in pixels. (Default: 400)
>   
> --**height=[height]**                 Image: image height in pixels. (Default: 400)
>   
> --**url=[url]**                       URL to PUT updates to. (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**log**                             Write crash logs to destination directory. (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**quiet**                           Suppresses progress output. (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**scheme=[scanline|pyramid|file]**  Enumeration scheme that defines the order in which tiles will be rendered. (Default: "scanline")
>   
> --**job=[file]**                      Store state in this file. If it exists, that job will be resumed. (Default: false)
>   
> --**list=[file]**                     Provide a list file for filescheme render. (Default: false)
>   
> --**metatile=[num]**                  Metatile size. (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**scale=[num]**                     Scale factor (Default: undefined)
>   
> --**concurrency=[num]**               Number of exports that can be run concurrently. (Default: 4)
>   
> --**files=[path]**                    Path to files directory. (Default: "C:\Users\USERNAME/Documents/MapBox" on Windows) (Default: "/home/USERNAME/Documents/MapBox" on Ubuntu)
>   
> --**syncAPI=[URL]**                   MapBox API URL. (Default: "http://api.tiles.mapbox.com")
>   
> --**syncURL=[URL]**                   MapBox sync URL. (Default: "https://tiles.mapbox.com")
>   
> --**syncAccount=[account]**           MapBox account name. (Default: "")
>   
> --**syncAccessToken=[token]**         MapBox access token. (Default: "")
>   
> --**verbose=on|off**                  verbose logging (Default: "on")
>   
> --**config=[path]**                   Path to JSON configuration file

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Export command line options are officially documented at https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/exporting/.